# Are many tabs in one page, or many HTML pages better for SEO?

Tags: seo, html, tabbed-content

I have an SEO question that concerns views with [tabs or pills](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp). Underneath each of those tabs or pills, there is some extra content.

Should I use one HTML page with those, or should I create own HTML page for each menu content, so that when someone clicks on Menu1, he is redirected to the *.html* where content of Menu1 is active? What is better in terms of SEO?

Comment: I couldn't find an exact duplicate of this question,  but there are several other related questions that you might find useful: [Best way to let Google index page with tabs - SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96707/best-way-to-let-google-index-page-with-tabs-seo), [Will using tabs with JavaScript (jQuery) hurt my SEO because of crawlability?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21176/will-using-tabs-with-javascript-jquery-hurt-my-seo-because-of-crawlability)

Comment: I'm struggling with this, too, though the issue only recently started for us. A theater index page shows all current and past plays but current plays are shown with same content as their individual play pages have. Only the index page shows in results and poorly.

Answer (score 3):

Tabs are bad. Google counts content in closed tabs with less relevance, so only the content in your first, initially opened tab will be counted with 100% relevance. Or you'll setup you tabs so, that they are all initially opened.

HTML are quite better - fully crawlable and content is displayed to 100%.

But you can play the game and use this effect: if you have a kind of duplicated content on page, you know, like product variants or something the like - what you do want to place for your users, but don't want, that Google pays much attention to it), place it into closed tab and this content will be automatically downgraded in its relevance. On this way you enhance you user metrics (time on site or the like) and don't send negative content quality signal with your dc.

Comment: As he is talking about "some extra content" I'd suggest using document anchors (example.com/page#part1 example.com/page#part2).

Comment: @Seb i think so too. thats why i mean, it could be technically possible to initially open all tabs - they could be addressed directly