# How to index pages with tabs for SEO

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, tabbed-content

I have a page with five tabs. The page will load with the first tab opened. The remaining tabs are only visible by clicking the respective tabs; these contents are not loaded with AJAX and are available on page load. But Google does not index the content of the hidden tabs.

I want to know if the following approach will index the table contents. I can create append the URL with an additional parameter with the tab id; a JavaScript logic will check for such a parameter on page load and show/hide accordingly. This way there would be individual URLs that can be given to Google for indexing.

I am not sure if this will work, any comments/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Change the URL when changing tabs and open a different default tab for different URLs.   Search for "pushstate" to figure out how to do it.

Comment: read more https://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/16094-google-ajax-spa-indexing.html

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the suggestion. I think I understood your recommendation. I am following this suggestion on this URL: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96707/best-way-to-let-google-index-page-with-tabs-seo

Please confirm if that's the right one.

Comment: @nikant25 Thanks for sharing the blog URL, it's very informative.

Comment: What I learned from the resourced is that the page is getting indexed, but when clicking on the SEO results, the page is returning the parent URL. I am going to give the pushstate logic a try. I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Contents that are hidden in tabs are still read by the search engine bots. In the previous years, tabbed content might have some negative connotations. This is also applicable to toggles or accordion. You can check if the content is readable by the search engine bot using Browseo. You can also check it in the Google Webmaster Tools - the Fetch as Google tool.

check this out https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-says-now-ok-put-content-behind-tabs/178020/

Comment: Brwseo is a cool tool, I was able to see how the site is being read by the search engines. This helped me understand that the page content is getting indexed.

Comment: it's good to know that the tool helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Google Webmaster Console for indexing you website's content. Use google crawl tool and Crawl website as Fetch and Render without Javascript.